# No Wi-Fi after 16.04 Upgrade from 14.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I'm novice in Ubuntu. I installed LXLE (Ubuntu 14.04) a couple of months ago. It has been getting slow. So I upgrade to 16.04. But on starting 16.04, it doesn't finish starting, but stuck when trying to connect WiFi. 
By continuously hitting the power button, the LXLE desktop finally launched 16.04, but with Network discontinued / offline, showing error message: VBoxClient: the virtual Box kernel server is not running.

---

I ran `iwconfig` with following return:

```
wlan0:   
IEEE 802.11bg   ; ESSID:off/any ; Mode:Managed ; Access Point: Not-Associated ; Tx-Power=20 dbm ; Retry short limit:7   ; RTS thr:off   ; Fragment thr:off ; Power Management:off

l0:      no wireless extensions.

eth0:    no wireless extensions.
(Note: "eth0" is the ethernet logical name. I did not have ethernet cable connected.)
```

When I ran `sudo lshw -class network`, I got the following return:

```
- Network

description: wireless interface

product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)

vendor: Qualcomm Atheros

physical id: 0

bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0

logical name: wlan0

version: 01

serial: 00:24:2c:3f:5f:3c

width: 64 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus master cap_list ethernet physical wireless

configuration: boradcast=yes ;  driver=ath5k ;  driverversion=4.4.0-58-generic  ; firmware=N/A  ; latency=0  ; link=no ;  multicast=yes  ; wireless=IEEE 802.11bg

resources: irq:16   memory:55100000-5510ffff
```

I tried running several times `sudo service network-manager restart`.
It seemed to connect to my WiFi, but only for 3 or 4 seconds, then dropped off.

The computer is an old netbook: Acer model KAV60.
Microprocessor: Atom N270 @1.6GHz, Bus: 533MHz
RAM: 1014MB

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` returns:

```
01:00.0   Ethernet Controller [0200]: Qualcom Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)

Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [165b:e00d]

Kernel driver in use: ath5k

kernel module: ath5k
```

`rfkill list all` returns:

```
0: phy 0: Wireless LAN

Soft blocked: no ; Hard blocked: no

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN

Soft blocked: no ; Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | tail -n3" returns:

```
[307.436528] IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready.
[307.464360] IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready.
[307.612171] IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready.
```

`dkms status` returns:

```
Virtualbox-guest, 5.0.24, 4.4.0-58-generic, i686: installed
```

Hope the above additional info helps to identify the problem. Many thanks.

I apologize that I have to type above info instead of copying it from the Terminal because the desktop screen just keeps on going black.

Comment: Thanks GAD3R for your expeditious reply. I tried but it the wifi still does not hold for more than 5 seconds. However, I noticed that it is not my wifi name that showed in the Network. Probably the connection still failed. What do I need to do to make my wifi name to come up to the Network?

Answer (score 0):

Blacklist the `acer-wmi` module :

```
echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf
```

Reload the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -rfv ath5k
sudo modprobe -v ath5k
```

Comment: Thanks GAD3R for your expeditious reply. I tried but it the wifi still does not hold for more than 5 seconds. However, I noticed that it is not my wifi name that showed in the Network. Probably the connection still failed. What do I need to do to make my wifi name to come up to the Network?

Comment: Hi GAD3R, before I saw your reply, I have loaded a few command returns in my original Question section. After following your steps, the "rekill list all" only shows one item. The acer-wireless LAN is gone. Also the "dmesg | tail -n3" return shows the first 2 lines changed from wlan0 (wifi) to etho (ethernet) with only the 3rd line as wlan0.  All other commands pretty much have not changed. Any comments?

Comment: Try this command `echo "options ath5k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf` then reload the driver

Comment: Hi GAD3R, I followed your latest instructions. Unfortunately it still did not resolved. For very brief moment, only perhaps 5 seconds, network connected to my wifi. Then it disconnected. I had the netbook ran LXLE (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (kernel: Linux 3.13.0-92). It never had wifi connection issue. I read in some threads, 16.04 seems to have suspend and cannot resume wifi connection. Are there solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

my issues with network-manager resolved when I gave the wifi adapter a manual address with good DNS. Prior to this all available wireless routers were not shown and on reboot no DNS servers were written to /etc/resolv.conf